# System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute what is that?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my various bll classes that are used in the web app I've inhereted each method starts with

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Select, true)].
```

I've been using this for several years but now that I'm considering a Microsoft certification, I starting to wonder about things I've taken for granted.

I noticed that this changes slightly with the type of the method, whether it is an SELECT, DELETE, or UPDATE type.

What is the purpose of this and what is the terminology used to discribed it? Why should I used it?

Thanks,

Risho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation on MSDN about [DataObjectMethodAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataobjectmethodattribute.aspx) seems clear to me.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start, but what it doesn't explain is that I can declare the method without it and it works.

Comment: Of course, that would be because, as the documentation states *You can use the DataObjectMethodAttribute to identify data operation methods on a type marked with the DataObjectAttribute attribute so that they are more easily identified by callers using reflection.*  Thus if the caller is not using reflection to identify a method, it would work using some other means.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate you time and effort!